# Set markers under POI's (google maps v2)

Tags: android, google-maps, markers

How can I set markers under POI's? I need to show POI's always.
On this screen my current situation: [IMG_LINK](http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2017/06/06/0019/0964/1262532/32/497b3da469.jpg)

Sorry for my russian english (mistakes).

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
yourmap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(LatLng).title(String).zIndex(float));
```

Comment: Yes, I already set zIndex to 1.0 for current user's marker and other markers by default (0.0f?) May be, if I set "-1", it helps me. I will try this.

Comment: @РСИТ_ Yes you need to set negative float. Currently default zIndex it's 1.0

Comment: No, markers with -1.0f under marker with 1.0f, but above POI's. :(

Comment: @РСИТ_ So I don't know how to solve it, probably POI are inside map or something...